# Uso da biblioteca HtmlAgilityPack em código C# para aquisição de valor para variável

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Boa tarde Galera!

Bom pessoal, sou novo aqui no StackOverflow e essa é minha primeira publicação então por favor me perdoem caso eu faça alguma besteira.

Estou fazendo um programa em C# para tirar uma foto de cada pessoa atendida na empresa com as webcams instaladas nos PCs. Até ai tudo bem, consegui com ajuda de tutoriais na internet, fazer um programa que tire fotos da webcam e as armazene no nosso servidor central de maneira automatizada. Atualmente essas imagens são salvas a partir de parâmetros do próprio PC (Ex.: nome do úsuario do PC + data + hora .png) o que dificulta depois na buscas delas. É ai que nasce o problema e é onde eu preciso da ajuda de vcs, o sistema utilizado por nossos funcionários é um intranet rodando no navegador Internet Explorer e durante o atendimento o funcionário faz um cadastro da pessoa a ser atendida (Nome e outras informações). Eu preciso que meu programa "espione" algumas desas informações (mais precisamente o Nome da pessoa a ser atendida) e use como nome do arquivo de foto a ser salva. Já li algo sobre utilizar a biblioteca "HtmlAgilityPack" mas não consegui entender como aplica-la a situação. Preciso que o programa faça uma leitura da pagina da web (código html) atrás do valor "Value=???????" na linha do código referente a placa do veículo e utilize esse valor como parte do nome do arquivo.

Abaixo segue linhas do meu código referente ao salvamento automático da foto:

```
private void btnCaptura_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CaptureInfo.CaptureFrame();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
    }
    try
    {
        caminhoImagemSalva = @"\\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\CIRETRAN Criciuma\Arquivo Digital\Arquivo de imagem atendimento\Guichê 01\" + "Atendente 01" + Att.Value.constais() + " " + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + " as " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "h" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "min" + ".jpg";
        picWebCam.Image.Save(caminhoImagemSalva, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
    }

    {
        // calling method
        ExtractHref("https://sistema.detrannet.sc.gov.br/arearestrita/tela_principal.asp");
    }
```

Agora a parte do código referente a captura da informação na pagina:

```
static void ExtractHref(string URL)
    {
        // declaring & loading dom
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc = web.Load(URL);
        // extracting all links
        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("<INPUT onkeypress=javascript:maiusculo() onfocus=javascript:this.select() maxLength=7 size=12 value=?????? name=txtPlaca>"))
        {
            HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["value="];
            if (att.Value.Contains("value="))
            {
                // showing output
                Console.WriteLine(att.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Eu fiz e refiz o código de várias maneiras diferentes, mas não consigo capturar as informações html e colocá-las no nome do arquivo. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu acho que esse método utiliza o padrão do XPATH. 
//input traria todos inputs do documento.

precisa testar.

Comment: Nesse caso a pagina tem 3 inputs, eu queria só um pra simplificar mas se trouxer todos melhor ainda. Quanto ao método de salvamento, sabe dizer se está correto o uso de "Att.Value.Contains" para usar o que foi capturado nos imputs?

Comment: Agora consegui, era isso mesmo!

Comment: @Informatica6drp se esta resposta te ajudou na solução do problema, marque como "aceita". Caso tenha qualquer dúvida esses guias podem ajudar [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-sopt-vers%c3%a3o-curta)).

Comment: @Informatica 6drp Bom que tenha conseguido. Sugiro você pesquisar sobre como filtrar com XPATH. Ele pode ser usado pra XML também, pode pesquisar por atributos, texto, etc. Muito interessante e vai te dar uma boa visão. Se estiver com problemas para esta biblioteca, entenda que ela gera um documento parecido com XML, ou seja, você pode pesquisar sobre XPATH e como acessar NODES num XML utilizando Microsoft XML ou outro componente, a maioria é bem parecido.